# how to count same token on arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, count, token, cpu-word

i have an arraylist like this :

```
ArrayList<String>  hasil = new ArrayList<String>();
    hasil.add("saya makan saya");
    hasil.add("makan kamu saya");
    hasil.add("kamu dimana");
```

and i want to count token on arraylist.
output that i want like this :
saya = 3, makan = 2, kamu = 2, dimana = 1

i have code count like this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < hasil.size(); i++) {
        arr = hasil.get(i).split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            temp.put(arr[j], 0);
        }

    }
```

but output than i have like this :
3 , 3 , 2 . just count the token not the same token.
i have store the count of each word in Hashmap. and i want to check if word exist in hashmap then count++;
 I've tried to make code like this , but still wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> input : temp.entrySet()){
            if(input.getKey().contains(arr[i])){
                c++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("" + c);
        c=0;
    }
```

can anyone help me ?
thank you

Comment: Use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store the count of each word. In your for loop you may check if the word already exists in the `HashMap` increase the count for that word. Otherwise put the word in `HashMap` with count of `1`

Comment: @STaefi i have store count of earch word on hashmap . but how can i check if the word already exists in the hashmap.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)

Comment: You don't need to loop over the entrySet. You should just use the `map.keySet().contains(arr[i])` to check if a word(which I assumed to be stored in arr[i]) already exists in your map or not.

Comment: @Staefi thank you very helpful :)

Comment: @JackFlamp  thank you very helpful :)

Comment: Glad that helped :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ArrayList<String>  hasil = new ArrayList<String>();
    hasil.add("saya makan saya");
    hasil.add("makan kamu saya");
    hasil.add("kamu dimana");

    Map<String, Integer> tokenCount = new HashMap<>();

    for (String phrase : hasil) {
        String[] tokens = phrase.split(" ");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            Integer count = tokenCount.get(token);
            if (count == null)
                count = 0; // first time this token was found

            tokenCount.put(token, count+1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with Java8:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = hasil.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(elm -> Arrays.stream(elm.split(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(w -> w, w -> 1, Integer::sum));

System.out.println(counts);
```

The output would be:

```
{saya=3, dimana=1, makan=2, kamu=2}
```